# Add a coroutine after some coroutines have finished, in an already running event loop (same loop, same thread)

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio

I've read through a few similar questions on SO, for adding a coroutine to an already running event loop, some answers were tailored to the questions asked therefore didn't quite apply in my case; the most common ones are `asyncio.ensure_future(coro(), loop=my_running_loop)`, or for a threadsafe version it would be `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro(), my_running_loop)`; a last resort would be spawning another loop after the current one finishes.

I'll present my questions first:

1. Why didn't the first two methods work?
2. Apart from the third method, is there another way, preferably done in the class such that I don't have to start another loop after the loop inherent to the class finishes?

A simplified example of my scenario would be that there are 1000 items sitting on the other end of a REST-API and I have to pull all of them to do some analysis. However REST-API depends on the network connection, therefore intermittently I might have some items being simply timeout error (or empty); in this case, I'd have to make calls to REST-API again to fetch those failed ones.

Just to demonstrate my scenario without all the granularity (data specific rather than code logic):

```
import asyncio
import ItemType  # Enum
import async_rest_api
import pandas as pd

class DataSource:
    def __init__(self):
        # some settings on self
        # particularly:
        # self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        # self.item_names_to_process = some_df  # pd.DataFrame of one column named 'name'
        # self.unprocessed_item_names = []
        # self.result = pd.DataFrame()
        # super().__init__()

    def get_item_fetching_function(item_type: ItemType):
        if item_type == ItemType.One:
           return async_rest_api.get_item_type_one
        if item_type == ItemType.Two:
           return async_rest_api.get_item_type_two
        if item_type == ItemType.Three:
           return async_rest_api.get_item_type_three

    # args were of length greater than one, 
    # here I simplified it to just item_type and item_names.    
    async def get_items(self, item_type, item_names):  
        step_size = 500
        results = []

        for i in range(0, len(item_names), step_size):
            tasks = []
            for name in item_names[i:i+step_size]:
                tasks.append(self.get_item_fetching_function(item_type)(name))
            results.extend(await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exception=True))


        result = pd.concat([r[1] for r in results])
        processed_items_names = pd.DataFrame(results.name.unique(), columns=['name'])
        unprocessed = self.item_names_to_process.append(processed_items_names).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
        self.unprocessed = unprocessed.name.tolist()
        self.result = pd.concat([self.result, result])
        
        # Trial: I wrote another line here to add 
        # a coroutine to process the unprocessed items. 
        # I tried both in-thread and cross-thread, 
        # neither have worked and no error was thrown; 
        # the code just finished silently.

        # in the running thread

        asyncio.ensure_future(self.get_items(item_type, self.unprocessed), loop=self.loop)

        # or in another thread
   
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.get_items(item_type, self.unprocessed), self.loop)


    def wrapper_function(self, item_type):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.get_items(item_type, self.item_names_to_process))
    
    if __names__ == "__main__":
         import DataSource
         import ItemType
         import asyncio
         data_source = DataSource()
         names = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=1000))
         data_source.wrapper_function(ItemType.One)
         # Trial: the last resort would be to check on the `self.unprocessed` here, if it has values, I'll re-run `self.get_items`. This method worked, as expected.
         if len(data_source.unprocessed):
            asyncio.run(data_source.get_items(ItemType.One, data_source.unprocessed))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `asyncio.gather`  for a construct you have better control of.

It goes like this: when you call a co-routine function, you get a co-routine object. This object can

- (1) be directly awaited: your code pauses and wait for its completion in a linear fashion: therefore this is not suitable to launch tasks in parallel.
- (2) be promoted to a "task", them, whenever your code yield to the running loop, it will step through all existing tasks, before comming back to your code.

The thing with `asyncio.gather` is that it does 2 things: promotes all your objects that are not tasks already to tasks, and them *wait* for all of them to complete,  when the `gather` call itself is awaited.

You can either keep this same design, and just move the line `results.extend(await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exception=True))` to inside the loop on `i` (and bellow the loop on `name`): that would await for a full batch of tasks of "step_size" size, until they are over -
or, you can just create the tasks explicitly, and use `asyncio.wait` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) to retrieve results in parsels, controling how much you pause before adding the next batch of tasks.  (this will require a somewhat clever redesign - just calling `gather` for each of your setp_size batches will be much easier)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to make ensure I understand you correctly, we basically re-scope the tasks and let them finish first (once I move that line inside the `i` loop and below `name` loop), once they are finished I can ask the loop to do one more task by adding coroutine using `ensure_future` (after the necessary post-process I did with the data retrieved from one batch), for example. This way I don't need to fire up another loop outside the class.

Comment: I am very sorry, reviewing my code I found myself misplaced asyncio.gather statements in the example. I've just updated the code and what I actually did was indeed what I described in above comment. Like you said, the statement was already in the i loop and under name loop. You have led me to notice that I didn't `await` my `ensure_future`, the exactly reason there was nothing happened! thanks very much.

Comment: regarding `async.wait` I found that I probably can use `return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION` to control how much I wanted to pause and check on the exception. Once I am ready I can resume the data retrieval with that item which threw an exception.

Comment: Hi jsbueno! I am really confused that such a big framework only has limited use case like this. I tried to code a recursive coroutine that will stop until an outer control changes flag. But it won't work properly, do you know if there is way in python to realize it? https://onecompiler.com/python/3xxn4busd

Comment: @GeorgeY - I can't figure out what you really want. It would be better for you to get some minimal code examples showing exactly  what you want to achieve and post a separate question to the site.

Comment: @jsbueno I want to print from "echo: 1" to "echo: 5". I have been deprived of the right to post a question.